# Angular 7 is there libraries to check lazy loading performance tree

Tags: angular, angular7

I am using lazy loading in my angular 7 project, and when I run the following:

`npm build --prod --aot`

I got the following:

```
chunk {0} common.0913107449ce910bce3f.js (common) 8.58 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.c6d0e41cf66977823213.js () 14 kB  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.e89188e71cd964268db5.js () 407 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3.33139e095dcdc99938cc.js () 62.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4.ebda0bbcf86bc49de010.js () 408 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.2aad2eeebadc8b4b5cd2.js () 479 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} 6.03f5238fe37cf4a30218.js () 18.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {7} runtime.f6427d1efd0aebd99cd7.js (runtime) 2.56 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {8} 8.c81220186a7896b40e98.js () 201 kB  [rendered]
chunk {9} 9.cf6ecff537fab1ea2da1.js () 120 kB  [rendered]
chunk {10} main.5d49d1e040bce48af816.js (main) 950 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {11} polyfills.4e6addda4bdac3fbf7e1.js (polyfills) 58.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {12} styles.0ace7b519537cad1d56a.css (styles) 218 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {13} 13.3b05a7908f130641937a.js () 163 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14.cb38771e3a2dc30be680.js () 7.57 kB  [rendered]
chunk {15} 15.b85622d4429edf650325.js () 4.47 kB  [rendered]
chunk {16} 16.c9f6d17f9cb455e6782a.js () 3.64 kB  [rendered]
chunk {17} 17.7c0893ad5dc1b053e206.js () 3.94 kB  [rendered]
chunk {18} 18.2656773c2af908bb7c14.js () 227 kB  [rendered]
chunk {19} 19.d29460e5effdc355660c.js () 215 kB  [rendered]
```

We all know, the concept of lazy loading. But are these chunk sizes are normal ? Or should I do something to change the structure using libraries?

Take note that the dist folder builded is all about 13mb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is not so straightforward to define a guideline of what chunk sizes are acceptable or not, since it is very much dependent on the size and required structure of the application.

I think the sizes of the chunks that you've provided are acceptable especially when you consider that delivering those to the client side gzipped would reduce the size of the generated files by a large factor.

A build for one of the applications I am working on generated the following chunks

[image]

Notice how the main chunk size totals to 1.74MB... The reason behind that is this particular application under the hood has been based on many third party libraries which are included to the global scope (via `angular.json` scripts section). This means that the libraries are added as is to the main bundle.

If you want to try and reduce the size of your chunks, try the following

- Identify any libraries which you do not need which are added to the global scope
- Make sure that any third party libraries that are not added on the global scope are three shakeable (example libraries providing angular service which uses the `provideIn: root` notation)
- Make sure that services, components, directives etc needed by a single lazy loaded module are defined in that module.

Internally webpack (which is used by Angular Cli to bundle your application) builds a dependency graph and splits the chunks following some heuristics. This [article](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/split-chunks-plugin/) explains the different ways how chunk splitting can be configured via webpack.

Answer (score 1):

Hey There is a package which can be found on npm

```
https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-explorer
```

while making build use command ng build --prod --source-map=true

source-map explorer path to bundle.js file it will open a tree-like structure in DOM showing the size of each and every part of application

Comment: What do you think about the chunk sizes ?

Comment: Yeah they are ok, use source-map-explorer to find what is occupying maximum space